# How to make synchronous API call in coroutines?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I need to call API in for loop for each element, but it has to wait for each API call to return values, because if it will be asynchronous, order of returned elements could be mixed because each of those requests are asynchronous calls.

I want to wait inside for loop till value is returned. I used `await()` for this but it is not working as expected. Results are returned after for loop.

Code:

```
parts.forEach {p->
            if (p.listEmpty){
                validItems.add(PartItem(TYPE_WITHOUT_LIST, p))
            } else {
                launch {
                    val listReturned = getItemsForPart(p)
                    validItems.add(PartItem(TYPE_WITH_LIST, p, listReturned))
                }
            }
}

private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
private suspend fun getItemsForPart(p: InnerItemPart): List<InnerPart>{
        val partResp = CompletableDeferred<List<InnerPart>>()
        scope.launch{
            val parent = api.getParentOfPart(p.partId)
            var filteredParts = emptyList<InnerPart>()
            if (parent != null){
                val startIndex = parent.innerPart.indexOfFirst { it.partId == p.startId }
                val endIndex = parent.innerPart.indexOfFirst { it.partId == p.endId }
                filteredParts = parent.subList(startIndex, endIndex).toMutableList()
                if (filteredParts.isNotEmpty()) filteredPart.removeAt(0)
            }
            partResp.complete(filteredParts)
        }

        return partResp.await()
}
```

Comment: Do you need to create this separate scope just for this function? If not, that's creating an unnecessary layer of complexity.

Comment: It is just for this. I'm normally using asyncTask in my App API calls. I dont have coroutines implemented in this App. But calling asyncTask with return value later in for loop is impossible. It will be always returned after for loop. And now it is happening again. I need to call this for majority of my items but at the same time I dont want to block UI thread. There is ProgressBar for user visible during this initialization.

Comment: @martin1337 you can use withContext it is a top level function highly optimized for returning values from coroutines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `launch` inside `forEach` you say to launch a coroutine and queue it to the context and let the next code run. So loop does not suspend (goes to for next iteration and so on).

If you look at the definition, [forEach](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each.html) is an inline function, which means it is going to be inlined at the call-site upon compilation so you can use suspending function directly there.

```kotlin
parts.forEach {p->
    if (p.listEmpty){
        validItems.add(PartItem(TYPE_WITHOUT_LIST, p))
    } else {
        val listReturned = getItemsForPart(p)  // suspends the current coroutine
        validItems.add(PartItem(TYPE_WITH_LIST, p, listReturned))
    }
}
```

You can use withContext for returning items it is lightweight and well optimized (unless you want to monitor child task, you don't need to create CoroutineScope).

```kotlin
private suspend fun getItemsForPart(p: InnerItemPart): List<InnerPart>{
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        // your old code inside the launch, just put filteredParts in last line
        filteredParts
    }
}
```

Comment: This iterated over whole list and value was returned after for loop ended

Comment: Also if I remove launch from that for loop it has error that it has to be called from another suspend function or coroutine. That for loop is part of other function

Comment: @martin1337 launch before running a forEach loop, forEach should be inside a coroutine in order to call another suspend function.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch a coroutine with `Dispatchers.Main` in function where you go though each list item and use `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` in `getItemsForPart()` function. `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` will change the context of the function to background thread:

```
fun applyForParts() = launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    parts.forEach { p->
            if (p.listEmpty) {
                validItems.add(PartItem(TYPE_WITHOUT_LIST, p))
            } else {
                val listReturned = getItemsForPart(p) // call blocks for each item
                validItems.add(PartItem(TYPE_WITH_LIST, p, listReturned))
            }
    }
}

private suspend fun getItemsForPart(p: InnerItemPart): List<InnerPart> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val parent = api.getParentOfPart(p.partId)
    var filteredParts = emptyList<InnerPart>()
    if (parent != null) {
        val startIndex = parent.innerPart.indexOfFirst { it.partId == p.startId }
        val endIndex = parent.innerPart.indexOfFirst { it.partId == p.endId }
        filteredParts = parent.subList(startIndex, endIndex).toMutableList()
        if (filteredParts.isNotEmpty()) filteredPart.removeAt(0)
    }

    return@withContext filteredParts
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have reasons for them that I don't see, but the scope just for this suspend function looks unnecessary since you aren't using it for encapsulating the task for cancellation. And the CompletableDeferred is an unnecessary extra layer of complexity. Use `withContext` for the simplest way to do some background work and return it when done to a suspend function.

```
private suspend fun getItemsForPart(p: InnerItemPart): List<InnerPart> =
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val parent = api.getParentOfPart(p.partId)
        var filteredParts = emptyList<InnerPart>()
        if (parent != null){
            val startIndex = parent.innerPart.indexOfFirst { it.partId == p.startId }
            val endIndex = parent.innerPart.indexOfFirst { it.partId == p.endId }
            filteredParts = parent.subList(startIndex, endIndex).toMutableList()
            if (filteredParts.isNotEmpty()) filteredPart.removeAt(0)
        }
        filteredParts
    }
```

And to further simplify the code:

```
private suspend fun getItemsForPart(p: InnerItemPart): List<InnerPart> =
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        api.getParentOfPart(p.partId)?.let { parent ->
            val startIndex = parent.innerPart.indexOfFirst { it.partId == p.startId }
            val endIndex = parent.innerPart.indexOfFirst { it.partId == p.endId }
            parent.subList(startIndex, endIndex).drop(1)
        }.orEmpty()
    }
```